# Two tables for one php/MySQL form with a common field?

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli

My form has an student ID , email and Name ...and checkboxes

I managed to store studentid and checkboxes in a table and created a new table to store all the other info related to the student id

Table 1 
studentid ----- checkboxselections....

Table 2 
studentid -----email ---- name

I have to insert into queries , one for studentid and checkboxes and one for (Table2)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";

    $sql2="INSERT INTO studentinfo (studentid, email, name)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$email', $fname)";
```

$sql2 fails to store data however $sql stores data just fine , how can I fix this ?

here's the full code

```
    $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_GET['studentid']); //echo $studentid;
        $email = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
        $fname = $dbcon->real_escape_string($_GET['fname']);

$name = $_GET['ckb'];
if(isset($_GET['ckb'])) //checkboxes
{
foreach ($name as $courcess){
$cc=$cc. $courcess.',';
}
}


    $sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$cc')";

        $sql2="INSERT INTO studentinfo (studentid, email, name)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$email', $fname)";


    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
echo "  Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration  ";   
        mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
```

**my form method is GET**

Comment: where you run $sql2? mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i recommended you to use prepare statements and transaction instead mysqli query .

you forgot mysqli_query with second query:

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb)
VALUES ('{$studentid}', '{$cc}')";

    $sql2="INSERT INTO studentinfo (studentid, email, name)
VALUES ('{$studentid}', '{$email}', '{$fname}')";


    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
     }

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql2)) {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
    }
 echo "  Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration  ";   
    mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
```

here is the example with prepare statement, and you don't need to use real_escape_string"

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO courses VALUES (?, ?)");  
$stmt->bind_param('ds', $studentid, $cc);
$stmt->execute();


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO studentinfo VALUES (?, ?, ?)");  
$stmt->bind_param('dss', $studentid, $email, $fname);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks, that was part of the problem I guess ..now this and Im sure its related to correctly defining $email $fname 

 Error: Unknown column 'myname' in 'field list'

Comment: $fname query, I redefined it as 
$fname =  mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['name']);
and now everything is fine however only the studentid is being stored in the second table , the name and email are not

Comment: $sql2="INSERT INTO studentinfo (studentid, email, name)
VALUES (".$studentid .", " .$email .", " .$fname .")";

Comment: I know you answered perfectly, but do you know why after replacing $sql2 or trying to fix the syntax I have the server "looses" the page, 404 not found....literally if I change one dot in $sql2 it looses the page :/

Comment: what dot exactly? i need to see an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60741/discussion-between-victorino-and-azizi).

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

`if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) 
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
    }
    else
    {
       if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql2)) 
       {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
       }
       else
       {
          echo "  Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration  ";
       }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbcon);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) 
 {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
 }
 else
 {

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql2)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
    }
}

Hope it will help.....
```